# Airflow RBAC for experimental API

Tags: airflow

I am exploring Airflow RBAC capabilities (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html?highlight=ldap#rbac-ui-security) and am disappointed to discover that they only apply to the Airflow UI, as far as I can tell it is not possible to determine what a user can do via either [the experimental API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html) or the [Airflow CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref). For example, I can restrict someone from triggering DAGs via the UI but they could still do it using the Experimental API or CLI.

I've just come here to verify that this is indeed the case and ask whether there is any other mechanism to govern usage of the experimental API or CLI? I flly suspect the answer to be "there is no mechanism to govern usage of the experimental API or CLI" but no harm in asking.

Comment: I asked in the community Slack channel if the plan to include this in the future.  They said they plan to release such features as part of version 2.0 some time this Fall.  For the moment we'll just have to be patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from Airflow 2.0, only users with permissions to trigger DAG will be able to do so via the new Stable API.

The old experimental API is deprecated.

CLI however does not have this mechanism yet, although you can restrict users to run certain commands via Linux permissions.